# PHP - How do I get `<?php the_content(); ?>` as a string or turn it into a string

Tags: php, wordpress

I use a lot the function:

```
get_search_query()
```

To get the value returned from searches and to be able to modify and use the string.

I need to know a function to get `<?php the_content(); ?>` as a string or how to turn what that function returns into a string.

The content is just a simple word with paragraph tags but using that function I also get the tags, I want to get just the text so I can add it to a hyperlink.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're looking for `get_the_content()`, which is well documented: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content

Comment: While this *is* likely the best approach, note that `get_the_content()` is *not* simply `the_content()` with the content returned instead of printed.  One important difference is that `get_the_content()` does not filter the content.  So, for example, if you use shortcodes to embed videos, contact forms, etc., they will not work by default with this approach.  You'll also want to run `apply_filters("the_content", ...)` on the content.  More info from the WP Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content#Alternative_Usage

Answer (score 5):

If you need to store it in a variable with html formatting do this

```
apply_filters('the_content',$post->post_content)
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know WP, but the implied naming convention would suggest `get_the_content()`. Additional googling reveals a variation [get_the_content_with_formatting](http://www.web-templates.nu/2008/08/31/get_the_content-with-formatting/)

An alternative would be however to wrap the_content() into `ob_start()` and `ob_get_contents()+ob_end()`. The latter returns any `print` output made until then.

Answer (score 2):

You should use get_the_content() in order to make get it into a string, which you can format.

Answer (score 0):

```
$the_post = get_post();
$the_post->post_content;
```

Full list of things you can get using this method:

```
[ID] =>
    [post_author] =>
    [post_date] => 
    [post_date_gmt] => 
    [post_content] => 
    [post_title] => 
    [post_excerpt] => 
    [post_status] =>
    [comment_status] =>
    [ping_status] => 
    [post_password] => 
    [post_name] =>
    [to_ping] => 
    [pinged] => 
    [post_modified] => 
    [post_modified_gmt] =>
    [post_content_filtered] => 
    [post_parent] => 
    [guid] => 
    [menu_order] =>
    [post_type] =>
    [post_mime_type] => 
    [comment_count] =>
    [filter] =>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `get_the_content` doesn't return the same thing as what `the_content` displays. For that you need to do this:

```
$content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());

echo $content;
```